# In python tkinter, i want to make a button disapear and also run a define

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have code that will happily remove the button after it is pressed, or will run code but I cant make it do both. I was wondering if there is anyway to do this.

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()

def start():
gamestart = True
#this runs the code at the end

#btn = tkinter.Button(window, text = 'Prepare to fight' , command = start)
#this would create a button that runs the code(but not perfectly)
btn = tkinter.Button(window, text="Prepare to Fight", command=lambda: btn.pack_forget())
#this creates a button that dissapears
btn.pack()
#creates button
window.mainloop()
if gamestart == True:
    lbl = tkinter.Label(window, text = 'WELCOME TO PYTHON COMBAT')
    #beggining of game
```

Comment: What do you mean "do both"? If you want to delete the button and execute other code, wrap all of the code in a function and call it when the button is pressed.

Comment: tried to put it into a function before but it did not seems to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is use `command` to execute a `definition` and also remove the `button` then you will simply need to call a `command` which removes the `button` and also executes whatever snippet you need it to.

This simply requires proper use of `lambda` to allow you to pass the variable which contains the `button` to the `definition`, like the below:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command(button):
    button.pack_forget()
    print("Command executed and button removed")

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda:command(button))

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

The above will only 'hide' the `button` meaning that you can `pack` it again later, the below will completely remove the `button`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def command(button):
    button.destroy()
    print("Command executed and button removed")

button = Button(root, text="Ok", command=lambda:command(button))

button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: If this answers your question can you please mark the answer as accepted for other users to see in future?

Comment: Be aware that this doesn't _delete_ the button, it only makes it invisible.

Comment: @BryanOakley user asked for a way to make it 'disappear', have updated my code to including `.remove()` if required